# Django Project - Update made inadvertently now failing

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django Project 3.0.7 using Python 3.8.  Something was updated inadvertently [like the title says] and I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Any assistance is appreciated, full traceback below:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d.%d is not supported." % VERSION[:3])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 3.0.7 is not supported.
```

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 3.0.7 is not supported.`  Did you update your Django?

Comment: `backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])` Could it be your database library? Like MySQL server or psycopg2 ...

Comment: @RedCricket, the django library did get updated from 3.0.7 to 3.1.1 unintentionally by a teammate working on the project.

Comment: The error message says you are using Django 3.0.7.  What's in your requirements.txt?

Comment: @SamkitJain nothing is showing in VCS for settings.py and I am hesitant to start making changes without a better idea of what it is.  Thank you for the hint, I'll start there.

Comment: @RedCricket this is a new project and we haven't gotten it to a release level yet, so there isn't a requirements.txt.  I set it up so I know it was at 3.0.7, and it was updated to 3.1.1, I downgraded it back to 3.0.7.

Comment: @AlliDeacon You should always look at having a `requirements.txt` with versioning even if you have just started the project. Never postpone it. It should be one of the first things to do. Avoids any unexpected behaviour that may arise due to a library update (in case of missing versioning) and makes it easier to recreate the environment.

Comment: @SamkitJain noted, and will add that to my standard practices moving forward.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have either updated your Django version or the database backend. You can roll back to a previous working state if you are using VCS and try reinstalling the libraries (I hope you had specified the versions in `requirements.txt`).

The traceback

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python383-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d.%d is not supported." % VERSION[:3])
```

points to that you may have `DATABASE_ENGINE='sql_server.pyodbc'` which is supported via [`django-pyodbc-azure`](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/). Why? A quick GitHub search led me to the [line 12 of django-pyodbc-azure/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/blob/a902a956e2a492ec349d4637a618183c14216ec7/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py#L12) which is in sync with the traceback path. If you are indeed using that library, it looks like it works with Django 2.1 only. Are you sure you weren't using Django 2.1 when it last worked? Or maybe you installed this library after installing Django 3.x and it is correctly throwing an error in which case you should look for a different library for your database backend that supports Django 3.x or downgrade your existing version to 2.1.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on a GitHub search I did to find the database engine library.

Comment: I did go through each of my libraries, and updated them to the correct version. I am putting  a requirements.txt file together now to avoid this in the future.  much appreciated.